# Segmentation fault when using fortran intel's mkl dgemm with python ctypes already at very small matrices sizes

Tags: python, windows, fortran, ctypes, intel-mkl

This is a follow up on :

[Dll dependencies missing when using ctypes with fortran dll compiled with intel fortran compiler and linking to intel's mkl library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66355688/dll-dependencies-missing-when-using-ctypes-with-fortran-dll-compiled-with-intel)

I am still under windows. The fortran code in `mkl_example.f` :

```
    subroutine matmultmkl(M1, M2, M3, M, N, K) bind(c, name='matmultmkl')
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: matmultmkl
        use iso_c_binding, only: c_float, c_int
    
        integer(c_int),intent(in) :: M, N, K
        real(c_float), intent(in) :: M1(M, N), M2(N, K)
        real(c_float), intent(out):: M3(M, K)

        CALL DGEMM('N','N',M,K,N,1.,M1,M,M2,N,0.,M3,M)
    
    end subroutine
```

is still the same. I compile it with command line (in a cmd windows where I ran `compilervars.bat` before) using the following batch file :

```
@Echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "IFORT_INITIAL_FLAGS=-c -fpp"
SET "IFORT_OPTIMIZATION_FLAGS=/O3"

ifort %IFORT_OPTIMIZATION_FLAGS% %IFORT_INITIAL_FLAGS% /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.311\windows\mkl\include" -o mkl_example.obj mkl_example.f
ifort -dll -o mylib.dll mkl_example.obj /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.311\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win" mkl_intel_lp64.lib mkl_intel_thread.lib mkl_core.lib libiomp5md.lib
```

that has not changed either. Then I run the follow python script `mkl_example.py`, that I changed to point to the static and import libraries :

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.311/windows/redist/intel64_win/mkl")
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.311/windows/redist/intel64_win/compiler")
import time
from ctypes import *
import signal
import numpy as np
mylib = CDLL(r"C:/path/to/the/mylib.dll")

def main():
    mylib.matmultmkl.argtypes = [ POINTER(c_float), 
                                    POINTER(c_float), 
                                    POINTER(c_float),
                                    POINTER(c_int),
                                    POINTER(c_int),
                                    POINTER(c_int) ]

    mylib.matmultmkl.restype = None

    M=231
    N=231
    K=231

    a = np.empty((M,N), dtype=c_float)
    b = np.empty((N,K), dtype=c_float)
    c = np.empty((M,K), dtype=c_float)

    a[:] = np.random.rand(M,N)
    b[:] = np.random.rand(N,K)
    c[:] = np.full((M,K), 0.0)

    # Fortran mkl call
    start = time.time()
    mylib.matmultmkl( a.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float)), 
                        b.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float)), 
                        c.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float)), 
                        c_int(M), c_int(N), c_int(K) )
    stop = time.time()
    print(f"Fortran mkl \t {stop - start}s")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`dgemm` executes a matrix product. Here, I have two square matrices of size 231, which is a totally silly small size for a matrix product today, yet : the call to the fortran function triggers a segmentation fault. And doesn't if the size is 230 or smaller.

Still, I can't figure out why would the 231 size cause issues, so I thought about aliasing but don't see anything particular.

Comment: Does it crash with the reference BLAS instead of MKL? Does it crash in pure Fortran?

Comment: What if: `mi = c_int(M)`, `ni = c_int(N)`, `ki = c_int(K)`, and the last 3 arguments of `mylib.matmultmkl( ... , byref(mi), byref(ni), byref(ki))`?

Comment: You are passing single precision entities to DGEMM which expects double precision. Also M3 should probably strictly be Intent(InOut). Does fixing these correct the problem?

Comment: @IanBush Replacing `c_float` with `c_double` in the python only (not in the fortran in the iso c binding part where I left `c_float` even if I suspect it's bad) corrected the problem yes. Thanks ! Is python's `c_float` not the same at fortran `c_float` ?

Comment: That sounds a total mess. Either use double precision throughout and use DGEMM. Or use single precision throughout and use SGEMM. Not if using double precision you will also have to make the constants double precision. Unless you carefully make it consistent between the two parts I wouldn't trust it at all - you do have a way of checking the answers are correct?

Comment: @IanBush No no I will use same type throughout, yes. (I was just remarking, amazed, that it worked nevertheless, and apparently correctly ... But for what that means one single time ...)

Comment: @VladimirF I did not checked with reference BLAS instead of MKL, as I always used MKL, like since more that 10 years. I am under windows : what is reference BLAS there, btw ? (I remember having asked myself this question 10 years ago, and having found several versions but not a reference version.)

Comment: It does not matter, Ian spotted the problem I did not (although I did notice your use of float). The reference BLAS is http://www.netlib.org/blas/ with some binaries included in http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/

Comment: @VladimirF yes I know it doesn't matter but I was curious nevertheless, and was also about asking for lapack but you gave both links, thx you.